# Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 IDE don't save new bookmarks of project created in earlier IDEs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I developed a project in visual studio 2012 year ago but migrated to visual studio 2019. However, the bookmarks and the files opened won't save in the newer IDE. I have tried database and environment data clean up, cleaned solution and built, but it won't work. I have asked at least two times on Microsoft forum, now migrated elsewhere, to no avail. Any help?

Comment: I do not have VS 2012 installed but I have created a project in 2010, updated it to 2022. It did not preserve opened file layout, but all bookmarks were intact. I deleted all bookmarks, created new ones in a different location. All was the same after I reopened the closed project.
The same happened after upgrading the project from VS 2010 to 2019.
Do you have an earlier version of the Visual Studio installed? Can you reproduce this problem with other projects?

Comment: @JohnCz: Old versions were removed and only VS 2022 remains. Also past opened documents are also opened automatically and the current status is not saved.

Comment: Sorry, since I am not able to reproduce your issue, I am not able to help you. As the last suggestion: try to save settings, and reset VS. You can always import settings back if resetting dies not rectify your problem.